# Creating QGenericArgument

Tags: c++, qt

Have simple application for testing `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` purpose :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setText( int value)
{
    QString s = QString::number(value);
    ui->textEdit->setText(s);
}





void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QGenericArgument genericArg =  Q_ARG(int, 321);
    bool inv = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( this,"setText",Qt::QueuedConnection, genericArg);
    qDebug("inv = %d\n", inv);
}
```

I'm getting `0` in `setText` value. Where `321` is gone?

Comment: please add Qt version and declaration of window. Problem is unreproduceable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `QGenericArgument` : "This class should never be used directly. ".

And indeed, the problem is solved by following the manual:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    bool inv = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( this,"setText",
        Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(int, 321));
    qDebug("inv = %d\n", inv);
}
```

To understand why this is correct and your code does not, see hauron's answer, but in general you should follow the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at what's happening under the hood.

Seems the integer 321 is taken as (const) ref https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#Q_ARG:

```
QGenericArgument Q_ARG(Type, Type &value)
QGenericArgument Q_ARG(Type, const Type &value)
```

`Q_ARG` is just a macro:

```
#define Q_ARG(type, data) QArgument<type >(#type, data)
```

.. returning an object of class `QArugment`:

```
template <class T>
class QArgument: public QGenericArgument
{
public:
    inline QArgument(const char *aName, const T &aData)
        : QGenericArgument(aName, static_cast<const void *>(&aData))
        {}
};
```

... which in turn is based on `QGenericArgument`:

```
class Q_CORE_EXPORT QGenericArgument
{
public:
    inline QGenericArgument(const char *aName = Q_NULLPTR, const void *aData = Q_NULLPTR)
        : _data(aData), _name(aName) {}
    inline void *data() const { return const_cast<void *>(_data); }
    inline const char *name() const { return _name; }

private:
    const void *_data;
    const char *_name;
};
```

This entire chain holds just const pointers to the data, so a safe bet is the problem would be a dangling reference to a temporary.

Since the data 321 is just a temporary, it's first bound to a const reference when `Q_ARG` is resolved into a constructor, and that's OK.

However, according to cppreference interpretation of the standard: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary the problem seems to arise due to:

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject
>   thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the
>   lifetime of the reference, with the following **exceptions**:
>
> (...)
>
> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer
>   list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the
>   object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696)

If my interpretation is correct (not sure if `pointer == reference` in this case), then the program is in the happy undefined behaviour state (Qt would need to dereference a dangling pointer/ref when running `invokeMethod`).

Since it doesn't crash and uses a 0 value (how do you know it's invoked at all? have you debugged it?) could be your build configuration hides the problem.

Comment: I know about `0` from break point while debugging. But how to pass arguments for function then?

Comment: @vico since you can debug, I'd recommend placing a watch on `genericArg`. It will get copied for the `invokeMethod` call. Possibly Qt will copy the argument several times (not sure how they resolve this function call). Also, the cheap way is just to try defining the integer as a local variable, see if that helps since you no longer have a danling ref.